# HelloSign: what do role Me and Me(when sending) mean in a template?

Tags: hellosign-api

In the [documentation of HelloSign](https://app.hellosign.com/api/templatesAndApiWalkthrough#GetIDFromAPI), The following two roles of template are confusing.

- Me
- Me(when sending)

My questions are:

- Are they roles by default?
- What's `Me` role used for?
- Could you please provide a usage example?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Me in the context of sending an API call to the HelloSign API is the sender of the signature request. Me (when sending) would be used when you have a template and want to pass the value of the text field during the call using custom fields. Me (now) is when you are using embedded requesting or requesting. The [documentation](https://app.hellosign.com/api/templatesAndApiWalkthrough#GetIDFromAPI) link you are showing is for a basic signature request (not embedded requesting or requesting) so for your purposes, you can ignore me (now).

In the field pop-up menu under "Who fills this out?", select "Me (when sending)." This designates the field as a custom field that will be populated by your API request when you use the template to send a signature request.